# Is there any way to speed up my CPU performance?

Tags: laptop, cpu, performance, cpu-usage, overclocking

I am using a relatively (from a technical view) old notebook from 2012 (Asus Zenbook UX32VD) which is using an [Inte Core™ i7 3517U Processor](https://ark.intel.com/de/products/65714/Intel-Core-i7-3517U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz).

Unfortunately, it only has one HDMI Video-Out. For the sake of productivity, I am therefore using a USB3.0 graphics-adapter which is connected to an FHD Monitor. The HDMI-Output is connected to a WQHD Monitor.

So I am using 3 Monitors for my doing. However, as I recently started using Latex for my writings and often compile things in the background with still several other applications open I nearly come to a bottleneck as everything I do is extremely laggy, especially when I am doing things on the external monitor which is hooked up via USB.

I am not a big 'hardware-knowing' person, but I downloaded CPU-Z to check my CPU speed and saw that it just runs at about 1 GHz but should go even up. Maybe he is trying to save energy or so? Is there any way I can say please always run at maximal speed and don't look the power consumption as I use the notebook 95% stationary. 
More, is there any way I can set the Max TDP higher as the 17W? Or are there other things which can help?
Latex focus most on single-core performance, is there any way that I can say use 75% from CPU1 and underclock CPU2?

Or does even overclocking the CPU brings much more power (however I assume overclocking an ultrabook is not the best option)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your device only has one CPU, it has multiple cores, and your processor does not support being overclocked or underclocked

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are running windows here, and that you have not altered any Power Management settings.

By default, Power Management is set to balanced, trying to save energy and give power as best as it can. This does result in the CPU not going full 100% when it comes to multi tasking, which is what you want.

The first step would be to set the Power Management options to High Performance.

In Windows 10, you may need to first create a new powerplan that is based on the High Performance settings before you can switch to it.

I run music software on my laptop and after a fresh install, trying to use it, it was very laggy. Power Management was set to balanced. I changed it to High Performance, and all ran smoothly.

Now, if this is not enough, then the only option is to actually overclock your computer. For doing so, you need to have a device that actually can be overclocked. Given that you added the label laptop, it is very likely that yours cannot. You can't just change the cooler, so overclocking can be done, but the gain is likely minimal, given that a laptop by default already has to deal with heat as best as it can. Especially if you set it to High Performance as described above, which will push it even more to the limit, making sure the CPU will get hotter.

Given that you have not actually mentioned which version of windows you are using, if you are indeed using windows... if its not windows 10, installing windows 10 will likely give you a performance boost too, unless you are using windows xp. But even then, windows 10 has been benchmarked with a better score than xp in some cases. Windows vista is really slow, windows 7 is okay, windows 8 is fast, but windows 10 is faster still.

Comment: Oh wow thanks. Yes you are right, I am using W10 Edu. I changes the power plan and now the cpu, still in idle, is clocked with 1.9 Ghz. I will check if this solves my problems, thanks

Comment: @SRel - Worth pointing out you won't be able to overclock the CPU you have.  You also would NOT want to overclock a laptop, unless it was specifically built with that in mind, which your laptop was not.